# Ansible - Remove block of code between two comments (including the comments themselves)

Tags: regex, linux, ansible

I added the following lines of config to the /etc/resolv.conf file on our servers with Ansible as a temporary measure whilst some domain controller maintenance was going on:

```
# Start-Temp-NS-Flip
nameserver 172.31.6.137
nameserver 172.31.6.136
# End-Temp-NS-Flip
```

I deliberately added the surrounding comments to assist with later removal. However, I'm now struggling to remove the block again.

I've tried a number of different Ansible modules to do so, for example all the following (for the initial task below the regex matches the block when run through https://regex101.com/):

```
  - name: Remove block of code (lineinfile)
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/resolv.conf
      regexp: '^# Start-Temp-NS-Flip\n.*\n.*\n\# End-Temp-NS-Flip'
      state: absent
      backup: true

  - name: Remove block of code (blockinfile)
    blockinfile:
      path: /etc/resolv.conf
      marker_begin: '# Start-Temp-NS-Flip'
      marker_end: '# End-Temp-NS-Flip'
      state: absent
      backup: true

  - name: Remove block of code (blockinfile)
    blockinfile:
      path: /etc/resolv.conf
      block: |
        Start-Temp-NS-Flip
        nameserver 172.31.6.137
        nameserver 172.31.6.136
        # End-Temp-NS-Flip
      state: absent
      backup: true
```

No errors for any of these, I just fail to get a match. Can anybody identify what I'm doing wrong with any of these/suggest a viable method of removal? Everything else in the file needs to remain untouched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the best solution:

```
  - name: Remove block of code (blockinfile)
    blockinfile:
      path: /etc/resolv.conf
      marker_begin: '# Start-Temp-NS-Flip'
      marker_end: '# End-Temp-NS-Flip'
      state: absent
      backup: true
```

The reason it's not working is because you have ignored the `marker` setting. From [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html):

- `marker`:

  The marker line template.

  `{mark}` will be replaced with the values in marker_begin (default=”BEGIN”) and marker_end (default=”END”).

  Using a custom marker without the {mark} variable may result in the block being repeatedly inserted on subsequent playbook runs.

  Multi-line markers are not supported and will result in the block being repeatedly inserted on subsequent playbook runs.

  A newline is automatically appended by the module to marker_begin and marker_end.

  **Default**: `"# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK"`

So when you set:

```
marker_begin: '# Start-Temp-NS-Flip'
```

The default `marker` template will turn that into:

```
# # Start-Temp-NS-Flip ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

You need to modify `marker`, like this:

```
- blockinfile:
    marker_begin: Start-Temp-NS-Flip
    marker_end: End-Temp-NS-Flip
    marker: "# {mark}"
    path: filetoedit.txt
    state: absent
    backup: true
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew I was missing something simple. Thanks, that works seamlessly!